# Release vs Debug - Memory and CPU

Tags: android, ios, memory, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Are there many differences regarding CPU and memory consumption between release and debug builds in Xamarin apps (iOS or Android)? If so, what are they?

How can I profile an Android and an iOS app in terms of CPU and memory consumption, built for release?

Comment: There are native profilers for iOS and Android that will profile CPU/Memory and much much more, take a look at Apple's Instruments for iOS and Google's Android Studio (which packages the profilers into its installer). Xamarin has a tech article on using Instruments (search their dev site), not sure about Android, but there are many articles from Google and 3rd-party blogs that walk through all the features available.

Comment: @SushiHangover the problem is that these profilers you referred to only work for debuggable builds, not release builds. Thanks for the answer anyways.

Comment: That is not true, we use them all the time for release builds out of Xamarin, from memory and cpu profiling, network activity, GLES drawcalls/profiling, etc... We only perf profile with release builds and thus 'have' to use the native profilers (and ones from Nvidia Gameworks, etc....)

Comment: How do you do that? For Android, only debuggable apps appear on DDMS.

Comment: I'll try to find some time to write up a detailed answer, once you go through it a couple time it becomes fairly easy